# Split <ul> to two columns with CSS2

Tags: html, cross-browser, css

Is there a good cross browser solution for splitting a single `<ul>` into two columns, or is the best approach still to use two separate lists floated next to each other?  I'm looking for a single solution, so no CSS3 goodness is permitted if it would require alternative HTML to support older browsers.

Required browser support IE7+, FF3+.

Comment: Just a side note, as we speak about columns: http://www.columnal.com/

Comment: I don't think this is possible without using CSS3...

Comment: Are the width of each `<li>` going to be dynamic/auto or can you use a fixed width?

Comment: Fixed width.  It's looking like a couple of the techniques from Jamie Dixon's link will do the job.

Comment: Since Jamie's answer has now been deleted, here is the link he posted that helped me: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/

Comment: @shanethehat: Not sure why that wasn't converted to a comment but deleted outright instead, oh well. Do you still have the solution? If so, you could post it here. Otherwise, that's OK.

Comment: @BoltClock: unfortunately I can't even remember which project I was working on!

Answer (score 3):

I made a JSFiddle with basic non-CSS3 that seems to work.  Should be cross-browser and might be a good base for you to start tinkering a specific solution.

Here's a peek at the CSS:

```
ul {
    width:340px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul:after {
    content:".";
    clear:both;
    height:0;
    display:block;
    visibility:hidden;
}

ul li {
    margin:0 0 0 30px;
    padding:0 0 10px 0;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:140px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/grahamzibar/zdBvk/

Comment: Good effort, and will probably be useful to users searching now. Can't mark the answer as correct though, because the `:after` pseudo element is not supported by IE7

Comment: I thought it was just the :before pseudo element that wasn't supported in IE7.  Oh well!  I use to have my environment setup so I could test with IE7, but I'm not a web developer anymore :P  Cheers!