# css/html: display unordered list continuiously vertically inside fixed-height container

Tags: html, css

Not sure if this is possible without using Javascript, but I have an unordered list, displaying it vertically inside a container that has a finite height, let's say 150 pixels.  I want the unordered list to continue displaying to the right once it reaches the bottom.

Something like:

List Item ...

List Item ...

List Item ...

List Item ...

List Item ...

List Item ...

List Item ...

List Item ...

List Item ...

List Item ...

Comment: want you are trying to achieve, can we have the code..?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899646/split-ul-to-two-columns-with-css2

Comment: Thanks @3dgoo ... added that link here too for anyone else looking.