# Break an ul Menu with subcategories on hover in two columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, nested

Hi im wondering how to break a ul list, i search and i found alot of resources, but non of them where applied on a menu, i tried using something like this, [Split <ul> to two columns with CSS2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899646/split-ul-to-two-columns-with-css2) or this
http://csswizardry.com/2010/02/mutiple-column-lists-using-one-ul/

but i think i dont understand quite well cause i cant manage to build it..

i Made a JsFiddle, so you can see the big ul i need two break on 2 columns... (also one problem is there are other uls nested in the main  list.

http://jsfiddle.net/dvVn6/1/

Here is My HTML // CSS

```
<a  onclick="showdiv('stateCity'); " >
       <div class="selBox22" style="cursor:pointer; " id="toggle_value1">
           <div class="wrapbox22">Mi ubicación</div>
            </div>
       </a>

<!--New Code Start-->

   <div id="stateCity"   style="float: right; margin-left:45%;
height: auto;
width:600px;
border: 2px solid #000;
left: 16px;
margin-top: 0px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 90000;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 5px;
background:#E8E8E8; font-style:oblique; display:none;" >

   <ul>
   <li><strong style="font-size:16px; color:#660000; font-style:oblique;">Mi ubicación</strong>
   <span style="display:inline; float:right;"><a onclick="Hidediv('stateCity'); " style="cursor:pointer;">Close</a></span>
   <hr>
   </li>

<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Aguascalientes</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2228&01&city=Aguascalientes">Aguascalientes</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Baja California</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2251&02&city=Ensenada">Ensenada</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2276&02&city=Mexicali">Mexicali</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2310&02&city=Tijuana">Tijuana</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Baja California Sur</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2266&03&city=La Paz">La Paz</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Campeche</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2230&04&city=Campeche">Campeche</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2232&04&city=Carmen">Carmen</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Chiapas</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2306&05&city=Tapachula">Tapachula</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2317&05&city=Tuxtla Gutierrez">Tuxtla Gutierrez</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Chihuahua</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2236&06&city=Chihuahua">Chihuahua</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2248&06&city=Delicias">Delicias</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Coahuila de Zaragoza</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2227&07&city=Acuna">Acuna</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2279&07&city=Monclova">Monclova</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2291&07&city=Piedras Negras">Piedras Negras</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2297&07&city=Saltillo">Saltillo</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2315&07&city=Torreon">Torreon</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Colima</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2242&08&city=Colima">Colima</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2271&08&city=Manzanillo">Manzanillo</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Distrito Federal</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2277&09&city=Mexico">Mexico</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Durango</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2249&10&city=Durango">Durango</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2255&10&city=Gomez Palacio">Gomez Palacio</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Guanajuato</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2233&11&city=Celaya">Celaya</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2262&11&city=Irapuato">Irapuato</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2267&11&city=Leon">Leon</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2296&11&city=Salamanca">Salamanca</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Guerrero</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2226&12&city=Acapulco">Acapulco</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2237&12&city=Chilpancingo">Chilpancingo</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2261&12&city=Iguala">Iguala</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Hidalgo</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2290&13&city=Pachuca">Pachuca</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2316&13&city=Tulancingo">Tulancingo</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Jalisco</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2256&14&city=Guadalajara">Guadalajara</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2293&14&city=Puerto Vallarta">Puerto Vallarta</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2312&14&city=Tlaquepaque">Tlaquepaque</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2314&14&city=Tonala">Tonala</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2325&14&city=Zapopan">Zapopan</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Mexico</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2234&15&city=Chalco">Chalco</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2238&15&city=Chimalhuacan">Chimalhuacan</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2240&15&city=Coacalco">Coacalco</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2244&15&city=Cuautitlan Izcalli">Cuautitlan Izcalli</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2250&15&city=Ecatepec">Ecatepec</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2260&15&city=Huixquilucan">Huixquilucan</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2263&15&city=Ixtapaluca">Ixtapaluca</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2265&15&city=Juarez">Juarez</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2268&15&city=Lopez Mateos">Lopez Mateos</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2270&15&city=Los Reyes">Los Reyes</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2275&15&city=Metepec">Metepec</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2282&15&city=Naucalpan">Naucalpan</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2283&15&city=Nezahualcoyotl">Nezahualcoyotl</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2284&15&city=Nicolas Romero">Nicolas Romero</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2302&15&city=San Pablo De Las Salinas">San Pablo De Las Salinas</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2309&15&city=Texcoco">Texcoco</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2311&15&city=Tlalnepantla">Tlalnepantla</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2313&15&city=Toluca">Toluca</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2322&15&city=Xico">Xico</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Michoacan de Ocampo</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2281&16&city=Morelia">Morelia</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2318&16&city=Uruapan">Uruapan</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2324&16&city=Zamora">Zamora</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Morelos</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2245&17&city=Cuautla">Cuautla</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2246&17&city=Cuernavaca">Cuernavaca</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2264&17&city=Jiutepec">Jiutepec</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Nayarit</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2308&18&city=Tepic">Tepic</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Nuevo Leon</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2229&19&city=Apodaca">Apodaca</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2253&19&city=Garza Garcia">Garza Garcia</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2254&19&city=General Escobedo">General Escobedo</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2257&19&city=Guadalupe">Guadalupe</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2280&19&city=Monterrey">Monterrey</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2301&19&city=San Nicolas De Los Garza">San Nicolas De Los Garza</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2303&19&city=Santa Catarina">Santa Catarina</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Oaxaca</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2287&20&city=Oaxaca">Oaxaca</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Puebla</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2292&21&city=Puebla">Puebla</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2307&21&city=Tehuacan">Tehuacan</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Queretaro de Arteaga</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2294&22&city=Queretaro">Queretaro</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2298&22&city=San Juan Del Rio">San Juan Del Rio</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Quintana Roo</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2231&23&city=Cancun">Cancun</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2235&23&city=Chetumal">Chetumal</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">San Luis Potosi</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2239&24&city=Ciudad Valles">Ciudad Valles</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2299&24&city=San Luis Potosi">San Luis Potosi</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Sinaloa</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2247&25&city=Culiacan">Culiacan</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2269&25&city=Los Mochis">Los Mochis</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2273&25&city=Mazatlan">Mazatlan</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Sonora</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2258&26&city=Guaymas">Guaymas</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2259&26&city=Hermosillo">Hermosillo</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2285&26&city=Nogales">Nogales</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2288&26&city=Obregon">Obregon</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2300&26&city=San Luis Rio Colorado">San Luis Rio Colorado</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Tabasco</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2320&27&city=Villahermosa">Villahermosa</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Tamaulipas</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2272&28&city=Matamoros">Matamoros</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2286&28&city=Nuevo Laredo">Nuevo Laredo</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2295&28&city=Reynosa">Reynosa</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2304&28&city=Tampico">Tampico</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Veracruz-Llave</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2241&30&city=Coatzacoalcos">Coatzacoalcos</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2243&30&city=Cordoba">Cordoba</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2278&30&city=Minatitlan">Minatitlan</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2289&30&city=Orizaba">Orizaba</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2305&30&city=Tampico">Tampico</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2319&30&city=Veracruz">Veracruz</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2321&30&city=Xalapa">Xalapa</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Yucatan</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2274&31&city=Merida">Merida</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>


<li><a class="st" href="javascript:void(0);">Zacatecas</a>
    <ul class="ulCityDN">

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2252&32&city=Fresnillo">Fresnillo</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.php?page=location/change-city/2323&32&city=Zacatecas">Zacatecas</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>

</ul> 
</div>  
     <!--New Code Start-->
```

CSS

```
#stateCity{
 float:left;height:auto; width:600px; border:2px solid #000;left:16px; margin-top:0px;position:absolute;z-index:90000; border-radius:5px; padding:5px; background:#3FF;
    }
#stateCity ul{list-style-type:none;}
#stateCity ul li:hover{background:#CCC; width:inherit; cursor:pointer;}
#stateCity ul li ul{ float:left;list-style-type:none; display:none;position:absolute; margin-left:180px; background:#CCC;}
#stateCity ul li:hover > ul{ display:block; }

#stateIN{
 height:auto; width:600px; border:2px solid #000; margin:50px auto; z-index:90000; border-radius:5px; padding:5px; background:#3FF;
    }
#stateIN ul{list-style-type:none;}
#stateIN ul li { width:220px;}
#stateIN ul li:hover{background:#CCC; width:200px;}
#stateIN ul li ul{ float:left;list-style-type:none; display:none;position:absolute; margin-left:200px; margin-top:-19px; background-color:#CCC;}
#stateIN ul li:hover > ul{ display:block; }

.cmpbut
{
    width: 193px;
    height: 40px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}


.dv_over
{
     width: 1200px;
     height:29px;

     position:absolute;

     margin-top: 10px;
     margin-bottom: 15px;
     overflow: hidden;

     background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F4F4F4;
     border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
}
.dv_first_inner
{
     padding-left:0px;
     float: left;
     position: relative;
     left: 0px;
}


.dv_second_inner
{
    float:left; 
    margin-top:8px;
    width:1200px;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;  
}

.sad_next {cursor: pointer;float: left;height: 29px;right: 0px;position: absolute; width: 28px;z-index: 1001;}
.sad_previous {cursor: pointer;float: left;height: 29px;left: 0px;position: absolute;width: 28px;z-index: 1001;}
```

Comment: Create a minimal example that demonstrates the problem you are trying to solve.  Most people will look at this much code and just move on, not providing any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I just manage to did this, if you want to make two col.. hover menu.. heres the code..

http://jsfiddle.net/dvVn6/2/

The trick is to float the li element and write a different %, for the "root" li is 50%... this makes the 2 columns..

For the "inner" li set the width to 100%..

I set a #double id on your ul, you can see the fiddle. its all there.

Here is what i changed and add.

```
#stateCity ul{list-style-type:none;}
#stateCity li{  line-height:1.5em;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
  float:right;
  display:inline;}

#double li ul li {color:#000; width:100%;}
#stateCity li ul li{ float:right; }
#double li  { width:50%;} <span class="code-comment">/* 2 col */</span>
#double li ul li { width:100%;} <span class="code-comment">/* 2 col */</span>
```